# drawer does not open per gesture anymore (upgrade to react-navigation 3)

Tags: react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I upgraded react-navigation from v2.18 to the just released v3.0.0. Unfortunately the drawer menu does not open per gesture anymore. I installed and `react-native link`ed the `react-native-gesture-handler` library. Contrary, I can open the drawer via the open() API.

It seems everything is loaded but the gestures are not recognized or not processed. Any hints?

Comment: have you find any solution yet ?

Comment: i have found the solution from this post.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53394982/react-navigation-swipe-on-drawer-does-not-work-in-android