# react native navigation drawer : Drawer not closing when pressing an overlay

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

I have tried many suggestions from https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/5370 but none of them.

Drawer is closing fine in android platform. This is only happening in iOS.
I am not sure but something with `react-native-reanimated` or `react-native-gesture-handler` library versions.

I have also tried following steps from this link. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started/

Someone's help is much appreciated. Thanks

Below is my package, app and index files.

```
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.10",
   "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.5",
   "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.3.15",
   "@react-navigation/native": "^5.9.4",
   "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.14.4",
   "react-native": "0.64.2",
   "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
   "react-native-code-push": "^7.0.1",
   "react-native-collapsible": "^1.6.0",
   "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.0.0",
   "react-native-fast-image": "^8.3.4",
   "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.10.3",
   "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.7.0",
   "react-native-haptic-feedback": "^1.11.0",
   "react-native-image-picker": "^4.0.3",
   "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.4",
   "react-native-modal": "^11.10.0",
   "react-native-onesignal": "^4.1.0",
   "react-native-paper": "^4.8.1",
   "react-native-progress": "^4.1.2",
   "react-native-reanimated": "2.2.0",
   "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.2.0",
   "react-native-screens": "^3.1.1",
   "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
   "react-native-spinkit": "^1.5.1",
   "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
   "react-native-swiper": "^1.6.0",
   "react-native-switch": "^2.0.0",
   "react-native-tab-view": "^2.16.0",
   "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.1.0",
   "sanitize-html": "^2.3.3",
   "uuid": "^8.3.2"
```

index.js

```
    import {gestureHandlerRootHOC} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
    import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
    import App from './App';
    import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => gestureHandlerRootHOC(App));
```

App.js
first line as - `import 'react-native-gesture-handler';`

Answer (score 2):

try by Clearing the Cache of your React Native Project:
try this steps:

1. Clear watchman watches: npm watchman watch-del-all
2. Delete node_modules: rm -rf node_modules and run yarn install
3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*

Close all your stuff and Restart your pc
this might solve your problem

Comment: I tried that a couple times but not working still